# An unhandled exception occurred: withModuleFederationPlugin is not a function

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I am experimenting on **Micro Frontend architecture** for an angular application based on [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnp2L0_DrK7dtH3WXlhAQ30lHNgaDeWma).

> Code files here: https://github.com/itsmehrd/monolith. Branch: **mfe-configuration**

For the `first-micro-app`

- After configuring the `webpack.config.js` file,
- when I try running `X:\Monolith> ng serve first-micro-app`,
- I am receiving an error stating - **`An unhandled exception occurred: withModuleFederationPlugin is not a function`**

I tried

- `npm i --save-dev webpack` and retriggered `ng serve first-micro-app`. But the issue still persists.

FYI, the Node, NPM and Angular CLI versions installed on my machine

- Node

  ```
  node -v
  v18.16.1
  ```
- NPM

  ```
  npm -v
  9.5.1
  ```
- **Angular**

  ```
  ng version

  Angular CLI: 10.2.1
  Node: 18.16.1
  OS: win32 x64

  Angular:
  ...
  Ivy Workspace:

  Package                      Version
  ------------------------------------------------------
  @angular-devkit/architect    0.1002.1 (cli-only)
  @angular-devkit/core         10.2.1 (cli-only)
  @angular-devkit/schematics   10.2.1 (cli-only)
  @schematics/angular          10.2.1 (cli-only)
  @schematics/update           0.1002.1 (cli-only)
  ```

Please help me resolve the issue.